# Understanding Return in nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a configuration file with a config similar to the below

```
map $request_uri $redirectWithError {
  default "0"
  "~* /<uri>" "1"
}

location / {
 if ($redirectWithError = "1") {
   return 404;
 }
 
 location / {
   proxy_pass <another_address>
 }

 location /search {
   proxy_pass <another_address>
 }
}
```

My assumption was that when the condition in the "if statement" is true then we would return 404 error and the location blocks which contain proxy_pass wouldn't be executed. But from what I have tested and observed this is not the case. Even after the if statement is executed the location blocks are also getting executed.

Is there a way to avoid the location blocks here ? i.e., if the "if conditions is true" then return 404 else check for within the location blocks.

PS: I have gone through this [how-nginx-location-if-works](http://agentzh.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-nginx-location-if-works.html) and [If is evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/#:%7E:text=Directive%20%E2%80%9Cif%E2%80%9D%20is%20part%20of,to%20situation%20we%20have%20now.) to understand the inner workings of the if statements. But I wasn't able to find any blog which specifies how the return works

Comment: Why are you placing the `if` block inside a `location`? Place the `if` block in `server` context and it will be evaluated **before** any location is selected to process the request.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to use `if` to check URI? That's what `location` is for.

```
location / {
  proxy_pass <another_address>;
}

location /search {
  proxy_pass <another_address>;
}

location ~* /<uri> {
  return 404;
}
```

https://nginx.org/r/location